# Why $\frac{1}{nh}O(h)=o[(nh)^{-1}]$ and $O_p(h^2+(nh)^{-1/2})=o_p(1)$

Tags: asymptotics

> Suppose that we know: as $n\to\infty$, $h\to 0$ and $nh\to\infty$. Why does it follow that
>
> 1. $\frac{O(h)}{nh}=o[(nh)^{-1}]$,
> 2. $O_p(h^2+(nh)^{-1/2})=o_p(1)$?

I'm learning kernel density estimation from Li and Racine (2007). The above appeared on pages 9--12 of the text without any explanation. Could someone please help me figure them out?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that 
$$
f=\mathcal{o}(g) \quad \text{as} \quad x \rightarrow +\infty \quad \text{if} \quad \frac{f}{g} \rightarrow 0.
$$
Here, from your hypotheses, you have

1. $$ \frac{\frac{O(h)}{nh}}{(nh)^{-1}}=O(h)\rightarrow 0
       \qquad \text{giving} \qquad \frac{O(h)}{nh}=o[(nh)^{-1}] $$
2. $$ \frac{O_p(h^2+(nh)^{-1/2})}{1}=O_p\left(\max
       (h^2,(nh)^{-1/2})\right)\rightarrow 0  $$

giving
$$
O_p(h^2+(nh)^{-1/2})=o_p(1).
$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you please elaborate more on the steps $O(h)\to 0$ and $O_p(\max(h^2,(nh)^{-1/2})\to 0$. For the latter convergence, don't we need convergence in probability?

Comment: @yurnero Thanks. Recall that $f=O(h)$ implies $|f|\leq Ch$ for some constant $C$, thus you have $O(h)\rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ Please, what do you mean by writing $O_p(g)$ for some function $g$?